# How to use a .cer client certificate in order to perform a cURL request like this?

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am not so into SSL certificate and I have the following situation working with a client.

They ask me to generate a Server Root CA, I generated it using openSSL by this command:

```
#Generate Server RootCA
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyform PEM -keyout rootca.key -x509 -days 3650 -outform PEM -out rootca.cer
```

So basically this commang generated the **rootca.cer** certificate  and the **rootca.key** file. I provided them only the **rootca.cer** certificate that they installed on their system (on the balancer\firewall).

On this system are deployed some REST APIs. I have to develop a client that call these APIs. So now I want to try to perform **cURL** call from the shell. From what I know I have to use the previous Root CA to generate a client certificate that I will use to perform the call. Is it correct?

So I created this client certificate using this command:

```
#Generate Client Certiicate
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048

#Generate signing request
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.req -sha256

#Generate Client  certificate
openssl x509 -req -in client.req -CA rootca.cer -CAkey rootca.key -set_serial 101 -extensions server -days 3650 -outform PEM -out client.cer -sha256
```

Now I have this **client.cer** file that should be the client certificate.

So basically they give me a cURL exlample like this:

```
curl --location --request GET "https://apiName.companyName.it/ws-
application/service/distretti/_/_/_"
```

but I obtain the following error:

```
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to annuariows.notariato.it:443
```

I think it happens because I have to say to cURL to use the previous client certificate to perform my request.

So what have I to do to use this **client.cer** in order to correctly perform my API call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameters --cert and --key to specify a certificate.

I have used this statement before in a similar setting to yours:

```
$ curl -v -i "https://host.tld" --cert "certificate_pem_format.crt" --key "keyfile.key"
```

The -v option is to get verbose output, for further debugging if necessary. The -i option is to show response headers, also good for debugging. Please also find: [List of CURL options](https://gist.github.com/eneko/dc2d8edd9a4b25c5b0725dd123f98b10).

I have my doubts about whether this error that you specified is caused by the certificate. If you like to debug issues with the certificate, try using OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect host.tld:443
```